# javascript code obfuscation tool

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Is there a recommended javascript code obfuscation tool?

I have searched it in stackoverflow,and someone suggest the 'YUI compressor'.

However it just do the following:

1. remove the annotatation/white space/new line
2. replace local variable
3. or something ele.

But It does not replace the property of one object.

Say I have a code like this:

```
var a=obj.fun();
var b=obj.pro;
```

I want something like this:

```
var xxx,yy,zz;
xxx=obj['yy']();
yy=obj['zz'];
```

Then even people re-format my code,he can not even know the propery/methods of one object unless he re-do the method/property replacement.

This is just an example, I just want the tool do more obfuscation other than just compress.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the [google closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), it provides three levels of writing:

1. The first one is `WHITESPACE_ONLY`
2. The second one is `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`
3. The third one is `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

`WHITESPACE_ONLY` removes comments, trim line breaks and unnecessary spaces. The output code is identical to the source JavaScript.

`SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` also renames local variable and function parameters.

`ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` is the most aggresive, besides the optimization in the above two levels, it also does:

- global variable renaming
- remove uncalled functions
- function inlining

For the give example:

```
//INPUT CODE
function unusedFunction(note) {
  alert(note['text']);
}

function displayNoteTitle(note) {
  alert(note['title']);
}

var flowerNote = {};
flowerNote['title'] = "Flowers";
displayNoteTitle(flowerNote);
```

`WHITESPACE_ONLY` result is :

```
//WHITESPACE_ONLY OUTPUT CODE
function unusedFunction(note){alert(note["text"])}function displayNoteTitle(note){alert(note["title"])}var flowerNote={};flowerNote["title"]="Flowers";displayNoteTitle(flowerNote);
```

`SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` result is:

```
//SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS OUTPUT CODE
function unusedFunction(a){alert(a.text)}function displayNoteTitle(a){alert(a.title)}var flowerNote={title:"Flowers"};displayNoteTitle(flowerNote);
```

`ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` result is:

```
//ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS OUTPUT CODE
alert("Flowers");
```

I think the `SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS` and `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` meet your need.

Comment: it seems that the `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` mode may change the property or method of the object,but how about if one method is to be exposed for external use? So any coding-standard?

Comment: Yep, it will. That makes it powerful and dangerous. There are two solutions there - first combine all your js into one file and go compiling. This one has very limited usage. The second one is exploring the usage of externs - you need to manually declare the symbols you want to keep. `window['dontReplaceme'] = dontReplaceme;` will preserve the `dontReplaceme` function. Check [here](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#export) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/). In advanced mode it also refactors parts of your code and creates some performance improvements that way.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language, interacting with the browser, so it's almost impossible to do a proper analysis to find where an object can pop up in the code.

For these reasons you cannot safely rename the properties of an object.

Answer (score 0):

with my limited knowledge on this subject. I would like to suggest the google closure compiler:

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html

It says there that they do property renaming